# Excel Power Query: Error Handling

Tags: json, excel, error-handling, powerquery

In Excel I'm trying to import data from API: [image: Where data comes in as list]

But sometimes if there is no data I get this [image: No data found]

Problem is that there is another query that relies on this list and keep throwing error if there is one missing item from the long list: [image]

How do I error handle this? I tried If [HasError] Then Else clause but it doesn't work because the last step is expecting to expand Column 1 of the table.

Please help, I'm a SQL developer and this is as far as in the front development I could go.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this script:

```
"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Invoked Custom Function"),
```

This script is between the `Source` and `Expanded Column1` steps.

Comment: Sometimes the editor does "magic"  -- for a lack of a better word. If you open it in the `advanced editor` you'll see the missing steps.